Converting from a cgi based project to Flask
I have multiple python scripts on a VPS running Apache. These use cgi so I make http calls from my front end (VBA in Excel). I believe that this architecture is not optimal. I have installed Flask and am deciding how to call these scripts from Flask.
This is my Flask script:
from flask import Flask, request
appFlask = Flask(__name__)
@appFlask.route('/')
def access_param():
    p = request.args['params']
    Cmd = p.split("_")
    if Cmd[0] == "Test":
        from test_01 import Launcher
        return (Launcher(Cmd[1:]))
    if Cmd[0] == "MOWCommand":
        from MOWCommand_06 import MOW
        return (MOW(Cmd[1:]))
    if Cmd[0] == "ReportSystem":
        from Report_System_03 import DoReport
        return (DoReport(Cmd[1]))

The url is typically:
http://zzz.zzz.zzz.zzz:5001/?params=MOWCommand_GetClientDetail_10023_2024-03-25_565678

Each of the python scripts have a load of imports to support their functionality, some of them are queries and others do updates. I would appreciate a critical review of my approach.
